# where to find authentication code in gcloud?

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

when `gsutil config` is executed , i would need to enter in the authetication code. 
Where extacly I can find a authentication code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the URL provided in the message you receive (under '**Please navigate your browser to the following URL**').

It should lead you to the code which you need to use for the authentication.